# ReferenceError: event is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I press enter I get a ReferenceError in firefox and also Internet explorer. Does anyone know how to fix this please? :)

```
function status_post_comment(id) {

    if(event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {

        var check_comment = $.trim($('#status_comment_'+id).val());
        var comment = $('#status_comment_'+id).val();

    if(check_comment.length >0) {

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo $domain; ?>social/comment_ajax.php',
            data: 'id='+id+'&comment='+comment,

        success: function(result) {

            $('#append_comment_status_'+id).append(result);
            $('#status_comment_'+id).val('');
            $(".timeago").timeago();
            $('.comment_input').val('');

        }

        });

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe your function should be something like: function status_post_comment(id, event) {

Comment: Where are you using the function

Comment: `event` is not defined so define it! Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

`event` is only a global on IE and browsers that choose to emulate it. With standard browsers, `event` is an argument passed to your event handler. You haven't shown how you're hooking up `status_post_comment`, but where you're doing that, you'll want to ensure you pass along the `event` argument.

For instance, if you were hooking it up via `on("click", ...)`, you might use ES5's `Function#bind` (which can be shimmed for older browsers):

```
someElement.on("click", status_post_comment.bind(null, id));
```

...and update `status_post_comment` to accept `event`:

```
function status_post_comment(id, event)
```

(`id` comes first because we bound it, then the arguments given to the bound function follow it.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem!

I was using an inline onclick='status_post_comment(id)'

without defining event so obviously it wasn't working. I added event to the function parameter and now it works :]